# How to get a click event of an input element that moves when active?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

My website has input buttons that move 1px when they are `:active`.
And, I can't catch the click event in case that I click one's border, because it moves a little away.

Here is an example.
You can't get the click event.

**HTML:**

```
<input type="button" value="Click Me!">
```

​
**CSS:**

```
input{
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
}
input:active{
  position: relative;
  top: 50px;
  left: 100px;
}
```

​
**jQuery:**

```
$(function() {
  $('input').on('click', function() {
    alert('You caught me!');
  });
});
```

​
**DEMO:**

http://jsfiddle.net/duwYv/

Comment: You will be able to get the click if you won't change the position on 'active'.

Answer (score 0):

You could try `mousedown` instead of `click`: http://jsfiddle.net/duwYv/6/

Alternatively you could move the input with jQuery once it has been clicked: http://jsfiddle.net/duwYv/8/

Answer (score 0):

Here's the thing, `active` happens on `mousedown` while you're pressing the mouse button. You're trying to handle the `onclick` event which is fired after the click has finished

In your case, a "full click" never happens. I'm not sure about your question, but if you want to view the message the when the mouse button is pressed, change your code to:

```
$('input').on('mousedown'
```